# Появление предупреждения об уникальных ключах

Tags: reactjs

После добавлния первого элемента на страницу появляется ошибка: "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop.":

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ReactDevTools показывают ошибку прямо на MainView:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пробовал key на другие div'ы устанавливать, но без толку. Может ли это быть связано с тем, что `mainHeader`, после добавлания эл-та, скрывается через `dispay: "none"; // в обьекте, поэтому в кавычках`?

```js
return (
        <div className={`${classes.main} ${props.content.length !== 0 ? "" : classes.empty}`}>

            {
                (props.content.length === 0 ? (
                    <div className={classes.mainHeader}>
                        <Typography variant="h6" component="h2">Planet is not choosen...</Typography>
                    </div>
                ) : (
                        <div className={classes.mainBody}>
                        {
                            props.content.map((content, i) => (<>
                                <div key={i}>
                                {Object.getOwnPropertyNames(content).map((name, j) => (j < 11 ? <DataLine label={name} data={content[name]} highlight={props.highlight} key={`${i}-${j}`} /> : ""))}
                                </div>
                                {(props.content.length > 1 && i < props.content.length  - 1) ? (<Divider className={classes.divider} />) : ""}
                                </> : "")
                            )

                        }
                        </div>
                ))

            }
        </div>
    );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обернул DataLine в DataBlock и дал React.Fragment'у key.